# Recursion with alertify.js leading to auto-closing alerts

Tags: javascript, callback, settimeout, alert, nonblocking

I am trying to convert the following old school snippet to [alertify.js](http://fabien-d.github.com/alertify.js/) 0.3.8:

```
window.doPrompt = function() {
  var str;
  do str = prompt("Enter your name");
  while (str === "" && (alert("Can't be empty!") || true));
  if (str) document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += ("<pre>Your name is: " + str + "</pre>");
}
```

[JSFiddle of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/J2pbZ/)

This is what I first tried:

```
window.doPrompt = function() {
  alertify.prompt(
    "Enter your name", 
    function(confirmed, str) { 
      if (confirmed) { 
        if (str.length === 0) {
          alertify.alert(
            "Can't be empty!", 
            function() { doPrompt(); }
          ); 
        } else {
          document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += ("<pre>Your name is: " + str + "</pre>");
        }
      }
    }
  );
}
```

[JSFiddle of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/9vbJm/)

It is not working as intended. For example, in Firefox 19, if you use the keyboard to submit the prompt empty, the "error" alert will only show for a very short time and will then disappear by itself, which is not how it worked before.

I tried breaking the recursion by inserting calls to `window.setTimeout` with the timeout set to `0` around each alertify call. It didn't help.

It is okay if you can recommend me an alternate JavaScript library with a similar API that I can use instead (that doesn't have this problem of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a problem with `alertify.js`, but with Firefox. If you search [bugs related to `transitionend`](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=transitionend) (used in the dialog animation, according to [the sources](https://github.com/fabien-d/alertify.js/blob/0.3.8/src/alertify.js)) you'll see some potential candidates for the issue you're experiencing (in particular ["transitionend event not fired when there are multiple transitions"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652543)). This is consistent with what you're experiencing - if you try to show a dialog while other is still in place (i.e. the previous dialog is still in the middle of a transition) then things break.

I can offer a workaround, though. It's not pretty, but gets the job done. But first, an unrelated problem I spotted in all browsers:

1. The library seems to become confused if you append stuff to the `body`; using a "target" `div` instead solves the issue:

   ```
   <div id="target"></div>
   ...
   document.getElementById("target").innerHTML += ("<pre>Your name is: " + str + "</pre>");
   ```
2. Both when showing an alert and when re-displaying the prompt, you should use `setTimeout` as you suggested. However, it's not enough for the timeout to be zero, since the problem here is on the `transitionend`. Set a value high enough for the previous dialog to finish hiding and the problem is fixed:

   ```
           setTimeout(function() {
             alertify.alert(
               "Can't be empty!", 
               function() {
                   setTimeout(function() {
                       doPrompt(); 
                   }, 500);
               }
             ); 
           }, 500);
   ```

   (if the value is not high enough, it will not only keep broken on Firefox but will also break once-working browsers like Chrome, so keep that in mind)

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/9vbJm/1/). Tested successfully in Firefox 19.0, Chrome 25 and Safari 4.0.4.